# Is it possible to tell whenever a particular user visits your website?

Tags: browser, google-analytics

Say I wanted to see how often my girlfriend looked at my blog (if at all) - would it be possible to set up some system which scraped data about every visitor and then checked to see whether it was her? I know the scraping technology is possible, but I'm not sure whether there would be any way of properly identifying her within a stream of data. Many IP addresses are dynamic and so, change with time; factors like browser version (which I sometimes use to narrow down results to individual instances in Google Analytics) are obviously liable to change if she downloads an update.

What's the closest thing we have to being able to being able to identify particular users without having them input details? Is there some sort of ID (for example, a unique code every mobile phone has) which can be collected when a user visits a site?

Comment: That would be a direct violation of the [GA TOS](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such ID, for good reason. Otherwise, every site we visit would track us and potentially spam us even more than is already the case.

If you don't have some way of knowing who a visitor is already (i.e., they are signed in, clicked a unique link that you gave only to them, previously visited from a given IP and gave you an email, or something like that), there's no way of knowing who visits your site.

*Note: technically, you can use a third-party tracking cookie. This is, however, not a good idea in most cases. Users hate it, and it's illegal in some places (like essentially all of Europe) without disclosure. In some places, it's illegal even with disclosure. Best practice: don't do it.*

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I thought this was the case, but then I couldn't understand how Adsense works. It knows what items I've been looking at, on which websites, and it can display them on other domains - so it doesn't seem to be cookie-based. Do you know how this works?

Comment: @Zetland Adsense is a third-party tracking cookie of the type I mentioned. When a website includes Adsense code, Google sends the user a cookie and can tell later on, even on a different domain, that it's the same user. People are pretty used to that when it comes to Google, so it's not an absolute no-no like some of the other options. But, you definitely still need to consider whether it needs to be disclosed in a privacy policy or even with a banner alert, depending on where you use it.